# объект Bundle равен null в onCreate()

Tags: java, android, activity, activity-life-cycle, onsaveinstancestate

Я сохраняю состояние активити в `onSaveInstanceState()`.

Если открыть список недавних приложений и закрыть моё, а потом запустить, в `onCreate()` передается null; а если не закрывать, а просто открыть другое приложение, а потом вернуться, `onCreate()` не вызовется.
`onRestoreInstanceState()` не вызывается никогда.

**UPD**
Как сохранить данные при закрытии приложения, чтобы когда пользователь откроет его потом, он увидел старое состояние активити?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Должно быть вы новичок в Android, но все мы с чего-то начинаем. Вам не хватает знаний о жизненном цикле активности. Подробнее можете прочитать здесь: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/lifecycle.php

Касательно ваших вопросов:

метод `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` вызывается при создании активности. Активность создается когда мы впервые её открываем или же когда меняем ориентацию с вертикальной на горизонтальную и наоборот. В первом случае `savedInstance = null`, потому что в нём нет информации и появиться неоткуда. Второй вариант интереснее. При повороте устройства старая активность уничтожается, но перед своим исчезновением успевает вызвать `protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)`. Значение `outState` передается в качестве аргумента в новую активность в метод `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`. Если вы явно не укажете какие параметры нужно передать в новую активность, то `Bundle savedInstanceState` будет равен null.

Разберём настоящее приложение. Для этого нам поможет инструмент LogCat. 
В методах onCreate, onSavedInstance, и onDestroy выведем в LogCat информацию, что именно этот метод был вызван. Пр-р:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.i("myTag", "call onCreate()");
        if (savedInstanceState == null){
            Log.i("myTag", "saveInstanceState == null");
        }
        else {
            Log.i("myTag", "saveInstanceState != null");
        }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.i("myTag", "call onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    Log.i("myTag", "call onSaveInstanceState");
    outState.putString("i", "j");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

[image: Logcat.jpg]

Пояснения к картинке

Строка 1. Мы заходим в приложение и тем самым запускаем главную активность. В этот момент запускается метод `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`.

Строка 2. В методе `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` мы сравниваем `Bundle savedInstanceState` с null. Соответствующую запись выводим в LogCat.

Строка 3. Мы меняем ориентацию экрана устройства. (переворачиваем из вертикального положения в горизонтальное или наоборот). Вызывается метод `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)`. Для того, чтобы `Bundle outState` не был пустым я предварительно в методе `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` добавил строку `outState.putString("keyForString", "The string I want to save.");`.

Строка 4. Активность уничтожается, вызывая метод `onDestroy();`

Строка 5. Создается новая активность, вызывается метод  `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`.

Строка 6. В методе `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` мы сравниваем `Bundle savedInstanceState` с null. Но в методе `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` мы добавили свою строку, которая находится в объекте `Bundle savedInstanceState`. Поэтому мы видим что `savedInstanceState != null`.

Строка 7. Я удовлетворился результатом и нажал кнопку назад. Т.о. мы закрыли текущую активность и видим, что вызвался метод `onDestroy()`.

Идём дальше

> а если не закрывать, а просто открыть другое приложение, а потом вернуться, onCreate() не вызовется.

Верно, метод `onCreate`не вызовется, вместо него вызовется метод `onStart`. По ранее указанной ссылке вы наглядно увидите, что после того как вы скрыли приложение вызовется метод `onStop`, а при возвращении вызовется `onStart`.

---

Пример из документации:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html?hl=ru#SaveState

### Сохранение состояния операции

> Когда начинается остановка операции, система вызывает метод
>   onSaveInstanceState(), чтобы операция могла сохранить информацию о
>   состоянии с помощью набора пар "ключ-значение". По умолчанию при
>   реализации этого метода сохраняется информация о состоянии иерархии
>   представления операции, например текст в виджете EditText или
>   положение экрана для ListView.
>
> Для сохранения дополнительной информации о состоянии операции
>   необходимо реализовать onSaveInstanceState() и добавить к объекту
>   Bundle пары "ключ-значение". Например:

```
static final String STATE_SCORE = "playerScore";
static final String STATE_LEVEL = "playerLevel";

...

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_SCORE, mCurrentScore);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_LEVEL, mCurrentLevel);

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

> Внимание! Реализацию суперкласса onSaveInstanceState() следует
>   вызывать во всех случаях, чтобы реализация по умолчанию могла
>   сохранить состояние новой иерархии.

---

### Восстановление состояния операции

> В случае воссоздания операции после предыдущего уничтожения
>   сохраненное состояние можно восстановить из Bundle, куда система
>   передает данные операции. Методы обратного вызова onCreate() и
>   onRestoreInstanceState() получают один и тот же Bundle, содержащий
>   информацию о состоянии экземпляра.
>
> Поскольку метод onCreate() вызывается, если система создает новый
>   экземпляр операции или восстанавливает предыдущий экземпляр, перед
>   попыткой чтения необходимо убедиться, что Bundle имеет состояние null.
>   В этом случае система создает новый экземпляр операции вместо
>   восстановления ранее уничтоженного экземпляра.
>
> Приведем пример восстановления некоторых данных о состоянии в
>   onCreate():

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // Always call the superclass first

    // Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore value of members from saved state
        mCurrentScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
        mCurrentLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LEVEL);
    } else {
        // Probably initialize members with default values for a new instance
    }
    ...
}
```

> Вместо восстановления состояния в onCreate() вы можете реализовать
>   метод onRestoreInstanceState(), который система вызывает после метода
>   onStart(). Система вызывает onRestoreInstanceState() только при
>   наличии сохраненного состояния для восстановления, и поэтому вам не
>   нужно проверять, имеет ли Bundle значение null:

```
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // Restore state members from saved instance
    mCurrentScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
    mCurrentLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LEVEL);
}
```

> Внимание! Реализацию суперкласса onRestoreInstanceState() следует
>   вызывать во всех случаях, чтобы реализация по умолчанию могла
>   сохранить состояние новой иерархии.

Comment: Все подробности написал, а главный вопрос забыл: как сохранить данные при закрытии приложения, чтобы когда пользователь откроет его потом, он увидел старое состояние активити? И где я могу использовать тот Bundle, который я сохранил в `savedInstanceState()`? Только при повороте?

Comment: И еще: я уже читал ту статью, которую вы мне прислали, и меня смутило это: "Если значение переменной savedInstanceState будет null, приложение запускается первый раз"

Comment: Вы не верно сделали выводы. Если активность создается впервые, то значение savedInstanceState будет null. Но постараюсь переписать предыдущий ответ